# ntpd local clock not immediately usable at boot

Tags: ntp, ntpd

When configuring an NTP server with only the local clock, the server isn't usable to clients until over three minutes after ntpd starts by default. This is with "server 127.127.1.0 prefer". I've been able to reduce the delay to 15-20 seconds with the configuration "server 127.127.1.0 prefer true iburst minpoll 4". Is there a way to remove the delay or reduce it further?

The version of ntpd I'm using is based on the one from ntp.org.

Comment: Do you need to use ntpd? Try chronyd. chronyd authors claim that their service synchronizes faster and with better accuracy. It says that here: https://chrony-project.org/comparison.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is no, [because it works as intended](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Emills/ntp/html/poll.html).
But it can probably still be reduced to 6 seconds:
Make sure `ntpd` writes the NTP drift file successfully.
Look in `man hwclock`, in the section called "Automatic Hardware Clock Synchronization by the Kernel", and ensure that the `hwclock` is written when rebooting.
The NTP server should have 4-10 accessible sources.